# How do i generate all possible subsets of an binary string?

Tags: c++, algorithm

i have a problem, that i don't know how to solve it.

i have a binary string and i want to generate all possible binary substrings.

Example :

```
input : 10111
output: 10000, 10100,00111,00001,10110 ...
```

How can i do this , fast AND Smart ?

Comment: What's a "binary string"? Does it contain binary digits in ASCII form like 0x30 and 0x31? Your example does not show substrings, but some kind of permutations or combinations. Please provide more detail.

Comment: with binary string i mean string s = "1000001010001" so a string that contains only zeros and ones :)

Comment: mr.bio, you might want to read about what a subset is. You can't have a subset of something that isn't a set. If I've understood your question, I don't think there's a standard name for what you're looking for. Maybe submask?

Comment: You can interpret this as a set problem if you consider the set of positions with the value of 1.  For the above example, the input set would be (counting from right to left): {0, 1, 2, 4} and the outputs would correspond to subsets {4}, {2, 4}, {0, 1, 2}, {0}, {1, 2, 4} (Edit: It would also help if I could count!)

Comment: all possible binary substrings should mean: the maximum number of unique, non zero binary strings that ORed together will give you the 'master' binary string?

Comment: By the way, the set of all subsets is the powerset.  So what you're effectively trying to produce is the powerset of the set of "set" bits in a binary string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magic - assumes bitmask though:

```
subset( int x ) 
    list = ()
    for ( int i = x; i >= 0; i = ( ( i - 1 ) & x ) )
          list.append( i )
    return list
```

You can use the same logic, though it's a little bit more involved, with a binary string.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind--damn I forgot you had it in a string and not a int/long/whatever.  You can still use the same logic though... Just count in binary but only use the positions that contain 1's.

Just thinking aloud.

Let's take the string 1001

What you want, I think, is the four numbers 1001, 1000, 0001 and 0000, is that right?

If so, what you are doing is counting the "ones" positions.

One way is to store off your original number

```
orig = n;
```

and then start iterating over that and every lower number

```
while(n--)
```

but each iteration, ignore ones that attempt to put 1's in the 0's position:

```
    if(n & !orig)
        continue;
```

If you expect it to be sparse--as in a lot of zeros with very few 1's, you could use a shifting mechanism.  So let's say your number is 1000 1001

Notice there are three 1's, right?  So just count from 000 to 111

But for each iteration, spread the bits out again:

n & 0000 0001 | n << 2 & 0000 1000 | n << 5 & 1000 0000

or the other way to think about it:

n & 001 | (n & 010) * 1000 | (n & 100) * 1000 000

This could be slower than the other solution depending on how many 1's appear though since it involves an inner loop with 1 iteration for each 1 in the original number.

Sorry about shifting between binary and decimal--I can do it all in hex if you like :)

Right now I can't come up with a pattern that directly maps bits without shifting--that would work best.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion

```
printsubsets(const string &in, const string &out)
{
  if(in.empty())
  {
    cout<<out<<"\n";
    return;
  }

  if(in[0]=='1')
    printsubsets(in.substr(1), out+"1");
  printsubsets(in.substr(1), out+"0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
vector<string> submasks(string in)
{
    vector<string> out;

    out.push_back(string(in.size(), '0'));

    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (in[i] == '0') continue;

        int n = out.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            string s = out[j];
            s[i] = '1';
            out.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

The algorithm does this:

1. Start with a vector containing just an empty bit-string '00000...'
2. For each 1 in the input string: create a copy of each string in the output vector with that 1 set.

I think that's pretty much optimal.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want values that are below the numeric value of the binary string, keep taking one away from the binary string until you get to 0.
2. If you want all values that can be represented by that number of binary digits, subtract 1 from the highest number that can be represented by that number of digits until you get to 0.

This kind of question appears on those code katcha sites